Trying to read txt file line by line in C Language
Basically my input file is in the format:
I 15 3 15 10 10 20  
S -5 3 15 82  
I -20 80 -4 10  
S 4 -20 8

The number of ints in a row can vary, but there is always one char at the beginning of each row
Based off the char value, 'I' or 'S', I insert or search for the given integers in that respective row. Seen as there is no EOL condition similar to EOF, how would I go about stopping at the end of the line? Ideally I would like to use fscanf.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void readFileLines(char** argv)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char read;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%c\t", &read) != EOF)
    {
        //scan first letter in line until EOF
        if(read == 'I')
        {
            //loop through all values in Line
            int data;
            printf("Inputting...");
            while(fscanf(fp, "%i\t", &data) != EOL) //ERROR (EOL DOESNT WORK)
            {
                //iterate rest of line values til end of line
                printf("%d\t", data);
                
            }
        }
        else if(read == 'S')
        {
            int data;
            printf("Searching...");
            while(fscanf(fp, "%d\t", &data) != EOL) // ERROR (EOL DOESNT WORK)
            {
                printf("%d\t", data);
          
            }
        }

        printf("\n");
        //iterate through to next line in order to scan different letteer
    }
   }

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
     readFileLines(argv);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

I heard that fgets could be useful in this scenario by utilizing the \n at the end of each line as a way to indicate when the line ends, but I'm not too sure how that method works. Please let me know!

If you replace your inside condition != EOL by != '\n' does it help ? maybe you need to check both for EOL and the newline character and break the main loop if you get the EOL character

Provided fgets() gets passed a large enough array, it will read a whole line and include the '\n' as the last character in the string. You can then ignore or erase it. char line[1000]; while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) { /* deal with line */ } /* all lines dealt with now */

I don't understand the following sentence: Based off the char value, 'I' or 'S', I insert or search for the given integers in that respective row. -- What exactly do you want to do when you "insert"? What exactly do you want to do differently depending on whether the first letter is 'I' or 'S'? Is the only difference that you want to print a different string, depending on whether it is an 'I' or an 'S'?

@Axnyff When would fscanf ever return \n? You probably mean != 1.


I heard that fgets could be useful in this scenario by utilizing the \n at the end of each line as a way to indicate when the line ends, but i'm not too sure how that method works.

fgets(), sometimes in combination with sscanf(), is pretty widely recommended as superior to fscanf(), especially for line-based input.  You can find documentation for it on line, in a variety of places.
But in your particular case, you don't actually have to consider your input as a series of lines.  You can instead consider it as a sequence of individual, whitespace-separated input items, some of them numbers, and others an 'I' or 'S' character.  Reading one field at a time via fscanf is fairly approachable here, with many fscanf pitfalls mooted, and you would not have the disadvantage of worrying about line length.  You would want here to take better advantage of fscanf()'s return value, which does not only signal end-of-input, but in other cases tells you how many input items were successfully scanned and converted.
Thus, you might do something like this:
    char c;

    // expecting I or S:
    int num_items = fscanf(fp, " %c", &c);
    if (num_items == 1) {
        // successfully read an 'I' or an 'S' ...
    } else if (num_items == EOF) {
        // end of input ...
    } else {
        // invalid input ...
    }

... and like this:
    // expecting numbers:
    // loop:
        int num;
        num_items = fscanf(fp, "%d", &num);
        if (num_items == 1) {
            // successfully read one number ...
        } else if (num_items == EOF) {
            // end of input ...
        } else {
            // Probably an 'I' or 'S' (which remains unread) -- end of record ...
        }


Thank you so much this really helped me out!


I heard that fgets could be useful in this scenario by utilizing the \n at the end of each line as a way to indicate when the line ends, but I'm not too sure how that method works.

I suggest that you create your own function which reads one line of input at once using fgets, and then another function which processes that line of input. You can then call these functions in a loop.
Although you could use the function sscanf for processing the input, that function has the disadvantage that undefined behavior will be invoked if the number is out of range of the target data type. For this reason, I recommend that you use strtol instead, which allows you to detect this situation and print an appropriate error message instead of invoking undefined behavior.
Here is an example:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>

bool get_line_from_stream( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp );
bool process_line( char line[] );

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    FILE* fp;
    char line[200];

    // check for correct number of command-line arguments
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Please specify an input file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // open input file
    fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // read the input file line by line and process the
    // individual lines, one line per loop iteration
    while ( get_line_from_stream( line, sizeof line, fp ) )
    {
        if ( ! process_line( line ) )
            break;
    }

    // cleanup
    fclose( fp );
}

bool process_line( char line[] )
{
    // process the first character of the line
    switch( line[0] )
    {
        case 'I':
            printf( "Inputting..." );
            break;
        case 'S':
            printf( "Searching..." );
            break;
        default:
            fprintf( stderr, "Error reading input!\n" );
            return false;
    }

    // process the remainder of the line
    for ( char *p = &line[1]; ; ) // infinite loop
    {
        long num;
        char *q;

        // convert one number
        errno = 0;
        num = strtol( p, &q, 10 );

        // test whether conversion was successful
        if ( p == q )
        {
            // skip all whitespace characters
            while ( isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
                p++;

            // test whether we successfully reached the end of
            // the line
            if ( *p == '\0' )
            {
                printf( "\n" );
                return true;
            }

            fprintf( stderr, "Encountered invalid character!\n" );
            return false;
        }

        // test whether range error occurred
        if ( errno == ERANGE )
        {
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "Could not convert character due to range error!\n"
            );
            return false;
        }

        // the character was successfully converted, so print it
        printf( " %ld", num );

        // make p point to the first non-converted character
        p = q;
    }
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input and remove the
//newline character, if it exists. On success, it will return true.
//If this function is unable to read any further lines due to
//end-of-file, it will return false. If it fails for any other reason,
//it will not return, but will print an error message and call "exit"
//instead.
bool get_line_from_stream( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp )
{
    char *p;

    //attempt to read one line from the stream
    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        if ( !feof(fp) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        return false;
    }

    //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //a missing newline character is ok if the next
        //character is a newline character or if we have
        //reached end-of-file
        if ( getc(fp) != '\n' && !feof(fp) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Line is too long for memory buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character by overwriting it with a null
        //character
        *p = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}

For the input specified in the question, this program has the following output:
Inputting... 15 3 15 10 10 20
Searching... -5 3 15 82
Inputting... -20 80 -4 10
Searching... 4 -20 8


I like John's answer, so long as the input file is under tight control and has no real possibility of invalid content. I.e. the input file is generated by some other program that will never output garbage. John's will catch a lot of bad input, but you can do more.
However, if the input file might be entered by a human, or by a program that might have a bug in it, then you should really do more validation and error reporting, which is almost impossible to do with fscanf.
Since your input is line-based, I would suggest using fgets() to read the lines. Then use strtok() to parse out the fields. Then use strtol() to convert the integers to longs, which should be range-checked before treated as ints. (Here's why I use strtol().)
Here's my code. I also accepted spaces as well as tabs as delimiters, and allow blank input lines. I think it does a good job of input validation.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char iline[256];
  int line_num = 0;

  while (fgets(iline, sizeof(iline), stdin) != NULL) {
    line_num++;
    char *token;

    token = strtok(iline, " \t\n");
    if (token == NULL) {
      continue;  // Ignore blank lines.
    }
    if (strcmp(token, "S") == 0) {
      printf("S");  // Process 'S'.
    }
    else if (strcmp(token, "I") == 0) {
      printf("I");  // Process 'I'.
    }
    else {
      printf("Error line %d, invalid prefix: '%s'\n", line_num, token);
      continue;  // Should return error; this is only for testing.
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    while (token != NULL) {  // Process each of the numeric fields.
      char *p = NULL;
      errno = 0;
      long val = strtol(token, &p, 10);
      if (errno != 0 || p == token || p == NULL || *p != '\0') {
        printf("Error line %d, invalid number: '%s'\n", line_num, token);
        break;  // Should return error; this is only for testing.
      }
      printf(",%ld", val);

      token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}


I'm curious: what kind of invalid input do you suppose would be handled better by this approach than by the one I outlined?

I haven't tried your code, but I think "SIS1 2 3" will be interpreted as S with zero integers, I with zero integers, S with 1, 2, 3.  Which, maybe is fine to accept. But I prefer to have a well-defined input syntax and enforce it. Also, this method won't allow you to print a message with the offending line number (which granted, I neglected to include).
